# How can I change planes in NifTI images?

Tags: nifti, niftynet

So I am trying to mix two different NifTI datasets, but when I view them in 2D they both have different planes, one of them is inverted also.

my question is:

1) How to change plane in NifTI?

2) Also how do I rotate the plane ?

thankyou in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62480134/edit) the post to include your own effort into solving this problem. The latter preferably in code, this is called a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: each `Nifti` image is subject to affine transform, the transform array is included in the header of the `Nifti` image, also you can rotate the whole array 90-degree using Transpose of the array.

Comment: @BelalHomaidanthanks this makes sense.